# Recursive call java script animate function, time dealy after each cycle

Tags: javascript, animation, jquery-animate

In ready function scrollDown animation begin,  in complete call back listener of scrollDown I called scrollUp function to commence the scroll up animation. After a cycle complete the scroll down animation take some time to start over again. **More importantly the delay time increases after every cycle complete.**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   scrollDown();
});
function scrollDown(){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop:$("#4").offset().top-100
    },
    {
        duration:2000,
        complete: function(){
           scrollUp();
        }
    });
}
function scrollUp(){
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop:$("#1").offset().top-100
        },
        {
            duration:2000,
            complete: function(){
               scrollDown();
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding **$('html, body').stop();** did the trick, now animation is quit smooth and no delay time. But why I have to call he stop() function? Because I already implemented the **complete** call back.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   scrollDown();
});
function scrollDown(){
    $('html, body').stop(); // no idea why I need to call this stop function
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop:$("#4").offset().top-100
    },
    {
        duration:2000,
        complete: function(){
           scrollUp();
        }
    });
}
function scrollUp(){
        $('html, body').stop(); // no idea why I need to call this stop function
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop:$("#1").offset().top-100
        },
        {
            duration:2000,
            complete: function(){
               scrollDown();
            }
        });
}
```